# Strange JSON.parse error in my Node.js hubot code

Tags: json, node.js, hubot

I am parsing the message on robot.hear:

```
robot.hear /^\[(.+)\]$/, (res) ->
  json_string = res.match["input"]

  try
    params = JSON.parse json_string
    console.log "success"
  catch error
    console.log "error"
```

with the following results:

[] -> success

[1,2,3] -> success

[true, false] -> success

["a": true] -> error #bad syntax as noted in answer below

['a': true] -> error #bad syntax as noted in answer below

["a","b"] -> error #added examples with correct JSON syntax
[{"a":"b"}] -> error #added examples with correct JSON syntax

In short, any [properly formatted?] json _string with single or double-quotes throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

`["a": true]` and `['a': true]` are not valid JSON. First off, JSON only recognizes strings with double quotes, so the second one is straight out. Then, JSON objects are enclosed in braces, like `{"a": true}`, not brackets like `["a": true]`; brackets denote an array, and arrays can’t have keys, so that’s also invalid JSON. As such, `JSON.parse` is correct in rejecting those strings.

Comment: of course you are right about bad syntax in ["a": true] and ['a': true], thanks. however both  [“1”, “2"] and [{"a": true}] still throw an error for me...

Comment: @user798177: In the first of your second set of examples, `[“1”, “2"]` has curly quotes, e.g. `“` and `”` instead of `"`. Your second example has straight quotes and is valid JSON, so that should work, but you should double-check that there really are straight quotes there rather than curly quotes.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, i was going nuts... turns out, Slack input i was using to parse had curly quotes instead of straight quotes even when i typed straight ones. What's totally weird is that all quotes except the last one  were curly, closing was straight.

Answer (score -1):

Try below :

[{"a": true}]

[{'a': true}]

You are not giving proper JSON object as input.